# How to automatically view a webpage sourceCode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to retreive results from a website into my ASP.NET (c#) application. (the required data are soccer fixtures results).

For what I've come to realize, I need to somehow use the "ViewState" right?

I actully need to somehow "right-click" the website and "select" "view source".. (I need this process to be executed automatically)

Can someone please explain to me how I can achieve that?

Comment: You might want to use the WebClient class to do this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: How are you consuming the data? What format does it need to be in? You need to provide more details before anyone can reasonably be expected to be able to help!

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate on this? I'm really confused as to what you are trying to do...

Comment: Are you trying to [scrape a webpage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about ViewState because it will be rendered on the page as a hidden html element with its corresponding value.

You can simply do this (taken [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx)):

```
Console.Write("\nPlease enter a URI (for example, http://www.contoso.com): ");
string remoteUri = Console.ReadLine();

// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Download home page data.
Console.WriteLine("Downloading " + remoteUri);                        
// Download the Web resource and save it into a data buffer.
byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData (remoteUri);

// Display the downloaded data.
string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
Console.WriteLine(download);

Console.WriteLine("Download successful.");
```

When you run above code you'll see that `download` has the actual html content, which is what you want.

Now, it seems that what you really need is an HTML parser that can allow you to get the content of specific section of page and do something with it. For that, the most popular tool is [HTMLAgility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Examples provided on the website.

Comment: Thank you very much Icarus! 
That's exectly what I needed. :) hope it will be of help to other people as well :)